# Loop being triggered DataAnnotations

Tags: c#

I am trying to use DataAnnotations and have them validate when I receive data from the clients.

So I have decorated my object with DataAnnotations.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SharedLib.Requests
{
    public class RegistrationRequest: RequestBase
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required"), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 7)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname is required"), StringLength(50)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname is required"), StringLength(50)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 7, ErrorMessage = "Password needs to be between 7 and 15 charactors")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I then receive an api call from my client. When the data is invalid, I get what I want, which is a result with the error listed.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace SharedLib.Requests
{
    public abstract class RequestBase : IValidatableObject
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> GetValidationResult()
        {
            return Validate(new ValidationContext(this));
        }
        public bool IsValid()
        {
            return Validate(new ValidationContext(this)).Count() == 0;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results, true);
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I receive a payload from the client which is valid, the code above gets stuck in a loop on the validate method.

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results, true);
        return results;
    }
```

If I breakpoint on the `var results` - it's just looping on that line, until my IIS crashes.

My register API method:

```
 [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegistrationRequest user)
        {

            //// Perform basic validation.
            if (!user.IsValid())
            {
                return BadRequest(user.GetValidationResult());
            }

            var auth = new AuthenticationService();
            // Make the request.
            RequestResponse reply = await auth.RegisterAsync(user);

            if(reply.Success)
                return Ok(reply);

            return BadRequest(reply);
        }
```

If I put a breakpoint on the `IsValid` call, my breakpoint never fires. It never hits that breakpoint. The model is being validated before that 'IsValid' check.

But when the data is valid, I'm getting caught in that method, and it's just looping, until crash.

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong?

Edit: Call stack:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that inside the TryValidateObject there is code:

```
// Step 3: Test for IValidatableObject implementation
            IValidatableObject validatable = instance as IValidatableObject;
            if (validatable != null) {
                IEnumerable<ValidationResult> results = validatable.Validate(validationContext);

                foreach (ValidationResult result in results.Where(r => r != ValidationResult.Success)) {
                    errors.Add(new ValidationError(null, instance, result));
                }
            }
```

So you get infinite recursion and your code never returns and dies because of stackoverflow. You don't need to implmenet IValidatableObject interface at all. Decorating with data annotation validation is enough to get validation.

Comment: If that doesn't help, set breakpoint to var results and then you hit it look at the call stack to see what initialised revalidation.

Comment: It's doing the same thing. I have a breakpoint on "var results = new List<ValidationResult>();" and another breakpint on "if(Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results, true))". When the "if..." breakpoint fires, it never gets to the return... it seems the method is recalled, and the breakpoint on "var results...." fires again. It seems the "if" statement is retriggering the method.

Comment: Can you post the stack

Comment: Added. It's just recalling the same line over and over.

Comment: Ah right! So I was bascailly re-doing what the DataAnnotations was doing? That's fixed it. Thank you for your assistance.